# c++ speed up for loop vector push back

Tags: python, c++, numpy

I have a vector and a matrix, and I am calculating the cosine distance between the vector and each member of the matrix. I've tried this operation in python and C++ and found that in C++ it is consistently slower.

Here is the code in C++, where `featureVector` is the matrix and `thisFeature` is the vector.

```
vector<double> cosineDist(vector<vector<double>> const &featureVector, vector<double> const &norms, vector<double> const thisFeature) {
    /*
    * Takes in one feature, the whole array of features, and perform cosine distance
    */
    vector<double> sims;
    const int featureVectorSize = featureVector.size();
    sims.resize(featureVectorSize);

    //Calculate norm of new feature
    double thisNorm = l2Norm(thisFeature);


    for (size_t i = 0; i < featureVector.size(); ++i) {
        double dotProduct = std::inner_product(begin(thisFeature), end(thisFeature), begin(featureVector[i]), 0.0);
        double denom = norms[i] * thisNorm;
        //sims.push_back(dotProduct/denom);
        sims[i] = dotProduct / denom;
    }

    return sims;
}
```

The same code in Python is as follows

```
vec = np.squeeze(feature)
norm_vec = np.linalg.norm(vec)

top = arr.dot(vec)
bot = norm_arr*norm_vec

out = np.divide(top,bot)
```

I tried adding memory allocation prior to the indexing or push back in order to remove that overhead, but it does very little. Does anyone know how numpy optimizes this?

For reference on my machine, the matrix has dimensions of (100000,256) and vector (256). This operation takes ~30ms in C++ but only ~18ms in python.

I would like to speed up the C++ code to be at least on par with the python, if not faster. Any suggestions would be very helpful, thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have updated the C++ code for the full function. I'm compiling using "Ninja" and x64 Release version on visual studio 2022.

The reason why I narrowed it down to the push/vector indexing is because the vector calculations by themselves are much faster (around 1e-5 seconds) if I don't then store the values into the vector.

Comment: I'm always hesitant to think too hard about optimization questions when there is no mention of your current compiler settings and test methodology. One issue of course is that you have undefined behavior in the code as posted, because you only _reserved_ vector storage in `sims`, but in the loop you are writing past the end. Note the actual size is still zero, unless you use `push_back`.

Comment: Regarding how numpy optimizes math operation, it's almost certainly using vectorized instructions for all multiplcations, divisions _etc_. And it probably also arranges the matrix in contiguous memory, whereas you apparently have a vector-of-vectors which is non-contiguous. This _can_ cause more cache misses, but again it's very hard to advise without seeing your entire test program and compiler settings.

Comment: You need to call `resize` instead of `reserve` on `sims`.  Reserve just makes resizes and adding additional elements faster, it doesn't resize the vector.  I don't see how your code doesn't crash as-is.

Comment: Adding to @paddy, you want `sims.push_back(dotProduct / denom);` (or `simes.emplace_back(dotProduct / denom);` makes no difference in this case), not `sims[i] = dotProduct / denom;` Or keep the current line, but change `.reserve` to `.resize`.

Comment: Also, std:: collection classes typically get amazing gains in speed when compiled with retail (or release optimizations). In Visual Studio, this is the "Release" build settings.  In g++ and clang, compile with `-O2`

Comment: @selbie @ShadowRange I've tried `resize`, it didn't speed up either. Also I did notice speed up in Release compared to Debug. The speeds are from Release.

Comment: @paddy That's interesting about numpy because I tried this code without `push_back` or vector indexing, the actual time for the vector calculations was around 1e-5 seconds. So I figured the bottleneck was with memory allocation and/or overhead from just storing everything in the vector.

Comment: Not all code is there, how do you call your function? Do you pass the std::vector by reference or value? Maybe you copy too much.

Comment: @ZWang - can you update your question to show a [mcve] that includes a `main` function and can be compiled by anyone on this sub? Same for the python code and provide a sample input set.

Comment: What are your compiler settings? I made a [dumb test on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/svq5a3sWW) which basically runs on a potato. Your function executes in about 50ms there with no optimizations enabled, but with -O1 it executes in 2ms.

Comment: @ZWang: To be clear, `resize` isn't to make it faster (pre-`reserve` should get the same benefit when compiling in release mode), it's to make it defined.

Comment: "The reason why I narrowed it down to the push/vector indexing is because the vector calculations by themselves are much faster (around 1e-5 seconds) if I don't then store the values into the vector." If you don't store the values into the vector, and you're compiling in release mode, a good optimizing compiler will skip the work entirely (not like anything sees the results, right?). This isn't Python, where the work will be done even if you don't save it; compiling C++ with full optimizations will generally not do any work it doesn't have to do.

Comment: I should make it clear when I talk about "vectorized instructions" in numpy, I'm not talking about C++ vectors: I'm talking about SIMD architecture which is a CPU feature for performing multiple calculations in parallel on a register. (Edit: oh, it seems I missed an order of magnitude there... Still, this demonstrates a complete program for doing timings, whereas you did not show one).

Comment: Related reading: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/avx-512-auto-vectorization-in-msvc/

Comment: @paddy I found the compiler during release, CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG

Comment: @ShadowRanger That's very helpful to know, I'm relatively new to C++ so thats actually very insightful. Thanks!

Comment: If you’re using visual studio, it has a built in profiler that highlights the problem areas right in your code window.

Comment: I will stress again that if you want any kind of repeatability on other machines, you must provide the exact benchmarking code you have written for both Python and C++. Not only does that enable others to run on their hardware and/or experiment with settings, but it also may provide insight into any invalid assumptions or poor testing methodology. Beyond this, consider that Numpy _might_ be executing parallel loops. If I take your code and make the outer loop parallel, the average drops from 25ms to 7ms on my i7-7700k. Using fast floating-point (`/fp:fast`) I get 12ms without parallel loops.

Comment: You are passing `thisFeature` by value. Please pass it by reference like the other parameters to avoid making a copy.

Comment: Are you sure python does a simple matrix * vector multiplication? It might use a divide&conquer algorithm to take down the cost from `O(n^3)` to around `O(n^2.8074)` or more complex `O(n^2.3728596). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication

Answer (score -1):

I see a lot of stuff getting passed by value including `thisFeature` and the return result.  It's possible modern compilers can optimize these issues out, but I typically follow the traditional approach of using out-parameters by reference (or pointer) for collection classes.

Instead of declaring your function like this:

```
vector<double> cosineDist(vector<vector<double>> const &featureVector,
                          vector<double> const &norms,
                          vector<double> const thisFeature)
```

Declare it like this, where `thisFeature` is passed by reference and `sims` is passed in as a parameter instead of being declared as a local variable.

```
void cosineDist(vector<vector<double>> const &featureVector,
                          vector<double> const &norms,
                          vector<double> const &thisFeature, // notice the ampersand that's been added
                          vector<double>& sims)
```

Then remove the local declaration of `sims` from the function. (But keep the `resize` call on it).

I don't see the local declaration of `l2Norm` in your code, but make sure you are passing `thisFeature` by const reference into that function as well.

And as I called out in the comments, benchmark with a release build with optimizations turned on.

Comment: Don't. That might have been beneffitial before c++11. Since then there is move semantic and copy elision: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision . Returning a vector will implicitly pass in the vector as argument and use it instead of `sims` just like your code. With one difference: In your code you have to construct a `vector<double> res;` to use as argument while `vector<double> res = cosineDist(...)` will only allocate the space and pass in an uninitialized vector. Out parameters are harder to read and slower.